# Connecting to clients using proxy server

Tags: tcp, proxy, operating-system, tunneling

I need to build some software infrastructure to manage computers which are connected to the internet using a 3G modem (about 30-40 clients).

The scenario that I came up with for project needs:

1. Client established internet connection (this is made on OS startup - no user action needed)
2. Client make connection to some server in internet (I named it "PROXY" - maybe there is a better name)
3. From now client is connected to PROXY server and it is listening for connections on some port (static or dynamic port?)

The same is true for all other machines.

What I need:

1. When I connect to PROXY server I want to see list of all connected clients to it (optionaly time of connection, client IP etc)
2. I can make connection to any clients but not P2P I want to connect using PROXY server (some kind of tunneling?)
3. Access to client should be impossible without PROXY server.

Example:

1. Client connect to internet using 3G modem - received IP: 149.10.20.30
2. Client connect to PROXY (79.10.11.12)
3. I connect to PROXY (terminal / VNC / putty / whatever). I can list connected clients (ex. using some command: $ show_connected_clients). And I see list: IP / MAC or other informations.
4. From my computer (or PROXY server if this is simpler) I can make connection to client (terminal / VNC / RDP whatever) using for this PROXY server.

   $ connect_to 149.10.20.30 using 79.10.11.12

Is such a thing is to realize with the help of the built-in OS services? Or maybe I need to use some commercial software or write my own application?

Writing this from scratch is possible but I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Some advice? Thanks in advance for any help.

PS. Clients OS (probably all) is Linux. PROXY server OS - I can make decision by my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decide to use VPN. Perfect in its simplicity. If someone is interested.

1. Client connects to VPN. Gets IP from VPN network
2. VPN server on PROXY server
3. My machine connects to VPN
4. On PROXY server I can list connected clientes to VPN
5. Using (ex RDP) I can connect to any client by VPN network

I think I can configure client to deny connection from other network then VPN. If so, I have everything I need.

Simple :)